# open new page without closing current page and pass some value to that page

Tags: asp.net

i am having 2 aspx page called **newpage1** and **newpage2**
i want to redirect user to another page  in asp.net without closing current page and also want to pass some value to that page.
right now i am doing this:

response.redirect("new page.aspx"?eid= " + 1 " & name=" + jinesh )

but this is closing my current page.
can any one provide me code how to redirect user from newpage1 to newpage2 without closing newpage1 and also to pass vlue from newpage1 to newpage2 on button click event??

Answer (score 1):

See this code project page on a clever way to reuse code for opening a new window in aspx pages. It use javacript since openening a new window can only be done on the clientside.

[Response redirect into a new window](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/317410/Response-Redirect-into-a-new-window)

Comment: but i also want to pass some value to new page.

Comment: Then you need to modify the open window function to take in the parameter or parameters you need in the form of a query string on the url. Redirect(string url, string target, string windowFeatures, string myParameter) and change window.open("www.mysite.com/myPage.aspx?"+myParameter)